# list transparency across non consecutive slides

Tags: beamer, lists, transparency

I am trying to get

```
\begin{itemize}
\item foo %completely visible in this slide
\item bar %transparent in this slide
\end{itemize}
```

Then a bunch of other slides and after that:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item foo %transparent in this slide
\item bar %visible in this slide
\end{itemize}
```

Basically what you can do with tables of contents but for a list of items.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1>[label=test]
    \begin{itemize}[<+>]
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: (+1) ... Your `beamer` knowledge is remarkable!!!!

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks for your kind words and for removing this question from the list of unanswered!